# Confusing behavior with `pip` and `pip3`

Tags: apt, python, pip

I originally installed `python3-pip` through `apt` and made the mistake of installing packages with `sudo` instead of as a user installation. I was getting a myriad of errors with tracebacks and import errors, so  I am trying to completely remove pip from my system and start fresh.

However, even after uninstalling all my pip packages and a `apt purge python3-pip`,

- `pip`, `pip3`, and `pip3.6` still show up in my tab-complete suggestions when I hit tab (on a new shell, after a restart).
- I have found a few python stub scripts in `~/.local/bin/`:

  - `~/.local/bin/pip`
  - `~/.local/bin/pip3`
  - `~/.local/bin/pip3.6`

These scripts are only ~10 lines each and just have imports for pip. However, when I moved these files out of this directory and reinstalled with `apt install python3-pip`, these files are not remade during installation.

I am confused what's going on, and what kind of hierarchy pip uses; it all seems a bit cryptic to me. What is the purpose of `~/.local/bin/` and why does `pip3` populate it with scripts, but only sometimes?

What can I do to ensure that `pip3`, along with ANY changes made after I installed/used it, are removed/reverted?

Comment: can u please tell me what problems you are facing and what you are trying to do?

Comment: Not a direct answer as such, but I recommend you take a look at Pipenv, it helps avoid a lot of this type of confusion: https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into it further, I learned that bash sometimes caches scripts in the `PATH` and puts it in `~/.local/bin`. As a result, even after an `apt purge`, programs are seemingly still these when the user attempts to tab-complete.

You can check if something is being hashed with:

```
$ type pip3
```

and you can clear hashes with

```
$ hash -d pip3
```

or

```
$ hash -r
```

Comment: AFAIK, Bash doesn't put anything in `~/.local/bin`. Maybe you did a `pip3 install --user --upgrade pip`.

Comment: Yes, I did! Do you know why it puts it in ~/.local/bin/?

Comment: Yes, explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989020/4518341